# stack ghci (intero): import between two standalone files

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have just two files `A.hs` and `B.hs` in a directory `dir` (so no cabal or stack.yaml files). `A` imports `B` (with just `import B`). Running `stack ghci` and loading `A` then fails, complaining about the import. Is there a way to get this working? Running the system-wide `ghci`, everything works fine of course.

The reason I'm asking is that I've switched to intero for Emacs, which uses stack, and I'd like to be able to use intero for random small bits of code that I have lying around.

Versions: ghc 8.0.1, stack 1.1.2.

Comment: Intero requires stack. It says as much on the front page. If you want some place to toy around with, why not create sort of a playground stack project?

Comment: @Cubic: I know it requires stack. I can indeed create a stack project, but I'm just wondering if there's a faster workaround for one-offs that I already have lying around.